# How to set href tag in javascript while writing html in the script

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the news in an object, and i want to show them dynamically in the page.

I have a problem setting the link to each of the news - the news url is in newsArr[x].url for each news.
The following is taking each one to **myPage/newsArr[x].url**, but I to access the variables while writing html.

```
let newsArr = response.news;
let text = "<div class='bg-primary'>"
for (let x in newsArr){
    text += "<div class='card bg-body-secondary'><a href= 'newsArr[x].url'> " + newsArr[x].title + "</a></div>"
}

text+="</div>"

document.getElementById("n").innerHTML = text
```

Comment: If that's an array of objects you should be using [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration##for...of_statement) rather than for...in. You may also find [a template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) easier to manage than string concatentation.

Comment: You do it correctly with `" + newsArr[x].title + "` no different than with the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre going to want to change it up a bit.
instead of putting in text to create divs, create the divs programmatically:

```
const box = document.createElement("div");
box.id = "box";
document.body.appendChild(box);
```

with this kind of code, you can then set the element href.
If you do it your way, after it was added you'll be hard pressed to be able to make changes to those divs programmatically. You lose the reference to the object since javascript is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just solved it
Hope it helps anyone

```
let newsArr = response.news;
let text = "<div class='bg-primary'>"
for (let x in newsArr){
    text += "<div class='card bg-body-secondary'><a href='" + newsArr[x].url + "'> " + newsArr[x].title + "</a></div>"
}
text+="</div>"

document.getElementById("n").innerHTML = text
```

Comment: youre shooting yourself in the foot, this code becomes very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

use `string concatination` to combine the static part of url with dynamic part of url

read the below updated code and it should be easy to understand and hopefuly that should solve the problem

```
let newsArr = response.news;
let text = "<div class='bg-primary'>";
for (let x in newsArr){
    text += "<div class='card bg-body-secondary'><a href='" + newsArr[x].url + "'>" + newsArr[x].title + "</a></div>";
}
text += "</div>";
document.getElementById("n").innerHTML = text;
```